# click button without id on vba to use on IE

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying to made a click on a button that does not have an ID or a Name; I tried using tabs, but it didn't work, and I tried the following code, but it doesn't do anything:

```
Set tags = Ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.Value = "Save" Then
        tagx.onclick
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

And here is the HTML markup:

```html
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Save</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `tagx.Value` is always empty. Check Html-Button Value attribute information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp).

The buttons seems to have `Span` with text *Save* or *Cancel* inside of it so you could check for `tagx.innerText` to find the save button and then call `Click` method on it.

```
Set tags = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.innerText = "Save" Then
        tagx.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```