# Click the button type in html with no name or ID using VBA

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to log in on the website using VBA excel code. The type of the button which I want to click is button and it has no name or id.

I have tried many many options, for example, `getElementsByName`, `InvokeMember("submit")` or `GetElementById`.

```
<button click.delegate="login()" class="au-target" au-target-id="36">
    <div id="pspinner">
        <span>login</span>
    </div>
</button>
```

There is no error, it just does nothing, it does not log in on the website.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734224/click-button-without-id-on-vba-to-use-on-ie

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith thank you, but unfortunately it still doesn't work, i think that the part with innerText doesn't work

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I changed for that      If tagx.getAtribute("click.delegate") = "login()" Then but there is some problem with clicking this button and still nothing

Comment: what is the website url please?

Comment: @QHarr it is internal portal of some application which my company uses, in the past it was working perfectly, but they changed the portal and the button is no longer input with id and name as it was before

Comment: If I go further I have the error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("button.au-target").click  ?

Comment: @QHarr unfortunetly still nothing, I think that maybe it is some problem with the button. After I insert login and password it became impossible to click, because when i make this website visible and i stop macro, i also cant click it after inserting login and password. Do you know what would it be?      objIE.document.getElementsByName("user")(2).Value = sht1.Cells(1, 2).Value

Comment: Some sites have elements with a disabled attribute for example. This can be toggled.

Comment: @QHarr when I insert login and password manually everything works perfectly, but when macro does it the attribute is disabled as you said, but this did not help   If e.disabled Then , it is some connected with some website settings?

Comment: sometimes an event like a keypress or the entry of text or focus is required. Maybe even a timing issue. Right click inspect the login button to pull up elements tab on right hand side and ensure you have the button html in view - then slowly manually perform login steps and monitor for any changes in the html during login.

Comment: @QHarr you mean i should check what happens in elements tab or in console?

Comment: in the elements tab

Comment: <button click.delegate="login()" class="au-target" au-target-id="36">
                        <div id="pspinner">
                            <span>login</span>
                        </div>
                    </button>  so first i have this and then after filling login and password and clicking the button something appears really quickly and then goes to the next page, @QHarr